# A problem related to limsup and liminf.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose $a_n >0$ and $b_n <1$ and lim $a_n=0$, lim $b_n =1$ and $A_n =\{x: a_n \leq x  <b_n\}$   then find limsup$ (A_n)$ and liminf$(A_n) $.

As $a_n$ goes to 0 and $b_n$ goes to 1, How can I use this condition to find  limsupA_n and liminf A_n, I got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally difficult to express $\limsup_n A_n$ and $\liminf_n A_n$ in terms of $\lim_n a_n$ and $\lim_n b_n$. The reason is that $\limsup_n A_n$ and $\liminf_n A_n$ are not topological notions, that is, they do not require the existence of a topology on $[0,1]$, whereas $\lim_n a_n$ and $\lim_n b_n$ are topological notions.

Since $a_n\to 0^+$ and $b_n\to 1^-$ (we know that $0 < a_n \leq b_n < 1$), we have that for every $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, there is an $n_0=n_0(\epsilon)\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $a_n < \epsilon$ and $1-b_n<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$, therefore $[a_n, b_n] \subseteq [a_{n_0}, b_{n_0}]$.

Then,

$$
\liminf_n A_n = \bigcup_{n\geq 1}\bigcap_{j\geq n}[a_j, b_j]
\supseteq \bigcup_{n\geq n_0(\epsilon)}\bigcap_{j\geq n}[a_j, b_j]
\supseteq \bigcup_{n\geq n_0(\epsilon)}[a_{n_0}, b_{n_0}] = [a_{n_0(\epsilon)}, b_{n_0(\epsilon)}]
$$

Since this holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, we can take $\epsilon \to 0^+$ to conclude that

$$
\liminf_n A_n \supseteq (0, 1).
$$

In fact, $(0,1)$ is the largest possible such set because we can see by the definition that $0,1\notin \liminf_n A_n$. Therefore, $\liminf_n A_n = (0,1)$.

Similarly, we may show that $\limsup_n A_n = (0,1)$.

Answer (score -2):

$(A_n)_n$ is an increasing sequence of sets, thus it converges to $\cup_n A_n=\liminf A_n=\limsup A_n$ and $\cup_nA_n = [0,1).$

Comment: Why is it increasing?

Comment: $(a_n)$ is decreasing and $(b_n)$ increasing.. right ?

Comment: No, they're not.. At least, nothing says they are.

Comment: More precisely, $(a_n)$ is eventually non-increasing.

Comment: No, not necessarily. What about, say, $\frac{2+(-1)^n}{n}$?

Comment: It goes to $0$ but the difference of two consecutive term has alternate sign. Thank you !